# Get SQL Function for AppropriateTimezone

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

We are connected to Health cloud and one of the Fields we dynamically populate for email content is operating hours. We have start time and end time field In Synchronized DE. In HC, the values are 7AM-7PM but when it comes to those fields in Sync DE it shows 1AM-1PM.I do understand CRM is in UTC and SFMC in CST without daylight savings.

I have a query which is pulling the `starttime/endtime` into a DE for Email Personalization. I would like to have the same hours (7AM-7PM) as shown in Health cloud.

What function/syntax do I need to use?

Comment: Please take a look at the `CONVERT` function as explained here https://mateuszdabrowski.pl/docs/sql/sfmc-sql-date-functions/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `AT TIME ZONE` in SQL to convert the time zone to UTC to match what is in Salesforce Health Cloud.

`SELECT starttime AT TIME ZONE ‘UTC’`

Here is more information on [Using AT TIME ZONE in SQL to Convert Time Zone](https://ampscript.com/using-at-time-zone-in-sql-to-convert-time-zone/)

Comment: Thanks it worked :) I tried doing in a diff way by using Date Add function and that worked too.

Comment: That's good news. `DateAdd` will work too but doesn't factor in daylight savings time.